# How to decide which component should be rendered dynamically in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

This is my structure:

```
const RootStack = () => ( 
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AddNote" component={AddNoteScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const HomeTabs = () => ( 
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="Customers" component={CustomersStack}/>
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

const HomeStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Tickets" component={TicketsStack}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const CustomerStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="Customer" component={CustomerScreen}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Tickets" 
       initialParams={{ parentRouteConfig: true }} 
       component={TicketsStack}
      />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const TicketStack = (props) => {
  const { route } = props;
  const { params } = route;

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator> 
      <Stack.Screen 
      name={params?.parentRouteConfig ? 'CustomerTickets' : 'Tickets'}
      component={params?.parentRouteConfig ? CustomerTicketsScreen : TicketsScren} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="TicketDetail" component={TicketDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

The problem is: In ticket stack I need to decide which screen should I render. FYI:  to navigate from drawer or any other higher navigator,
I needed to give different name to Screen. Current implementation solves the problem that I have. But it smells, I know that
there is a better solution for this but I can't find it. What is the best practice to achieve this? Instead of initialParams can I use different technique?

Comment: can you put your codes on github and leave a link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on react-navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#define-our-screens), I'm doing the following for all my "conditional screen".

```
 <Stack.Navigator>
    {params?.yourConditionVariable ? (
      <Stack.Screen
        name="CustomerTickets"
        component={CustomerTicketsScreen}
      />
    ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name="Tickets" component={TicketsScreen} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

It works pretty well, and it's the biggest feature of RN v5 on my side. I really love this flexibility!

Comment: Yes I like it too, and I use this actually in my other stack, It adds readability. However,  even if I do that still I need to pass a param from parent stack to child in order to know which component should I render right? I think that I emphasized the wrong part of the question. Is there any way to achieve that without passing initial params

Comment: Well, I think they designed initialParams exactly for this purpose. You can convert the stack to a function which returns a StackScreen, and adding a custom object as param. There you can use your object if you don't want to use props at route?.params level. But I think it's fair enough to use them :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right.Maybe I'm overthinking this. Maybe I can get the navigationState and get the parent instead of initialParams but still, it might be overkill. I don't know... But appreciate for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you can mark the answer it'd really help me!